# FileReader is not working in IE10 using Javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, filereader

Please help me out in overcoming my problem. The problem might be very simple but sorry for the noob question as I am new to javascript. Please bear with me for some time.

window.Filereader is not working in my project. I am running my project on IE 10. Even when I am accessing my project from the remote machine with IE 11 the problem is same.

I am using visual studio 2010 for the development.

I tried another code not working on my machine but the same code if created written on another machine then is working. I am posting the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" onchange="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>


function myFunction()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("myFile");

    var txt = "";

    if ('files' in x) {
        if (x.files.length == 0) {
            txt = "Select one or more files.";
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
                txt += "<br><strong>" + (i+1) + ". file</strong><br>";
                var file = x.files[i];
                if ('name' in file) {
                    txt += "name: " + file.name + "<br>";
                }
                if ('size' in file) {
                    txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes <br>";
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    else {
        if (x.value == "") {
            txt += "Select one or more files.";
        } else {
            txt += "The files property is not supported by your browser!";
            txt  += "<br>The path of the selected file: " + x.value; // If the browser does not support the files property, it will return the path of the selected file instead. 
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}

</script>

<p><strong>Tip:</strong> Use the Control or the Shift key to select multiple     files.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tested the code above in my IE11 and it's working fine. While IE10 has partial support for the File API, the code above should still work since you're just using the .files property. The code above does not use any of the constructor or function that is explicitly not supported by IE http://caniuse.com/#search=filereader. Have you tried saving it in a simple HTML file and view that file in IE10?

Comment: To see if what you're using does not really support FileReader, try out this code: 
if (window.FileReader) {
  // alert(success);
} else {
  alert('File API not supported in this browser.');
}

Comment: Yes I checked 

if(window.fileReader)
{
    alert(success);
}

Comment: @Roman, I am entering inside the else part of your code. Also I tried accessing my code from other machine on the network and the problem remains same. Is there any possibility of the problem with asp.net code. I don't know why but this line of code was working previously. I feel it to be very strange error or might be because I'm new to javascript. Please let me land your helping hands

Comment: 1) First things first, try saving your code above and test it in a simple HTML first before suspecting your ASP.NET code,...If you've tested your code above in a simple HTML file and the problem still exists then it's not with ASP.NET but the problem is with your browser....2) if there's ASP.NET code then share it.